# ACLを有効化したNomadクラスタのトークンを紛失した際のリカバリでLeaderノードを調べる方法はありますか。

Tags: untagged

下記の手順でNomadクラスタのACLを有効化しました。

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/nomad/access-control-bootstrap

ACLを有効化するとアクセスにTokenが必要となります。
Tokenを紛失した場合、下記の手順でリカバリする必要があります。

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/nomad/access-control-bootstrap#re-bootstrap-acl-system

リカバリの操作は、下記の通りで操作は難しくないのですが、1のLeaderノードがどれかを調べることができませんでした。

1. Leaderノードに接続
2. reset indexの確認
3. reset indexを$data_dir/server/acl-bootstrap-resetに書き込み
4. nomad acl bootstrapを実行

Tokenがない状態で、ssh接続は可能、Tokenがない状態でLeaderノードを調べる方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

下記のstatus apiで調べることができました。
https://www.nomadproject.io/api-docs/status

下記の通りTokenを設定しなくても、LeaderノードのIPアドレスを確認できました。

```
$ echo $NOMAD_TOKEN

$ echo $(curl -s $NOMAD_ADDR/v1/status/leader)
"10.15.81.108:4647"
$ nomad server members
Error querying servers: Unexpected response code: 403 (Permission denied)
$
```